How to make flask server run when react application is open
I have a problem with deployment flask + react project to heroku
My project consists of 2 parts:

The flask app that handles database and
The react app that works as the frontend when I run the project on local host.

So everything is fine, the project is open and gets access to the database.
But when I made the deployment to heroku it looks like the flask server is not run when I open the react project.
I've got the following error:

The name of  the flask project in heroku is customer-flask-data and its location in heroku is

https://customer-flask-data-final-1e31465d9b53.herokuapp.com

The env files in react project:
.env
REACT_APP_NAME=customer-flask-data the customers app (from .env)
REACT_APP_VERSION=1.0
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:5000"

.env.dev
REACT_APP_NAME=customer-flask-data the customers app (from .env.dev)
REACT_APP_VERSION=1.0

.env.production
REACT_APP_NAME=customer-flask-data the customers app (from .env.production)
REACT_APP_VERSION=1.0
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT="https://customer-flask-data-final-1e31465d9b53.herokuapp.com/"

authServices.js
import http from './httpServices'
const apiEndPoint = process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT+'/visitor_login'
// const apiEndPoint = config.apiendPoint + '/auth'
export function login(username, password){
    return http.post(apiEndPoint, {username, password})
}

The flask app.py
app=Flask(__name__)
......
if __name__=='__main__':
   app.run(port=5000)

I also tried
if __name__=='__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)

but it doesn't help
The error:
authServices.js:7
POST http://localhost:5000/visitor_login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

When I run the flask server in VC terminal and open the page on heroku, everything is working fine.
Please help me, resolve the problem, may be I forgot something on the react part.
Thanks a lot everybody.

The value of REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT is "http://localhost:5000" from the logs. Consider re-building in production mode. If you need more help, I’ll write up an answer.

I really appreciate you if you write me an answer, how rebuild in production mode

if name=='main':
port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
I tried that code but unfortunately it doesn't work-the same error

Which WSGI Server are you using? Try running this with the local Heroku CLI and share the content of your Proc file. If you're still encounter issues, share what you did and we can guide you.

OK
I tried now to use waitress

I changed app.py in the flask project into:

if name=='main':
from waitress import serve
serve(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)

I also changed the Procfile into:

web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT app:app

and I changed  .env in react part into:

REACT_APP_NAME=customer-flask-data the customers app (from .env)
REACT_APP_VERSION=1.0
REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT=http://127.0.0.0.0:8080

and I made deployment to heroku but got the same result just without a previous mistake, the flask server doesn;t response

just show the following:
WebSocketClient.js:16
WebSocket connection to 'wss://customer-react-final-9b6bf4c3695c.herokuapp.com:11244/ws' failed:

Share a [example]. Share enough info that can be used to solve this. Share the content of WebSocketClient.js.

function WebSocketClient(url) {
_classCallCheck(this, WebSocketClient);
this.client = new WebSocket(url);

this.client.onerror = function (error) {
  log.error(error);
};

}

the error in the line-this.client = new WebSocket(url);

Could you tell me please does the production server has an internet link?
I think may be i'm doing that wrong
